# How can I update another user attributes?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am currently logged in as a admin to the page and would need to update some users user attributes or should i let them handle it themselves?

Here is what I have so far in terms of the function.

```
  const updateUser = async () => {
    const username = email
    await Auth.updateUserAttributes(username, {
      'email': email,
      'custom:phonenumber': phonenumber,
      'custom:company': company
  })
  }
```

and the values for those are coming from here.

```
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [phonenumber, setPhonenumber] = useState('')
  const [company, setCompany] = useState('')
```

I heard about the `AdminUpdateUserAttributes` but not sure if I can use this and if I can not sure how to.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for granting an admin access to modify other user's attributes.

1. Use `AdminUpdateUserAttribute` in a API Gateway lambda integration. Perform your own authorization check using the access or id token. (check roles or sub value in token).
2. Use Cognito Identity Pool to grant temporary AWS credentials to admins with the `AdminUpdateUserAttribute` action.

Both approaches use the same API call just differ in how it is authorized. I personally prefer the former as it allows for more flexibility in authorization whereas identity pool is harder to set up with anything beyond simple role-based access control.